# Time complexity of algorithms

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have a question about time complexity. I don't really understand how to get if it's true or false.
So can someone tell me how to find a result? Explain it like for total newbie please.

Here are some examples:

1. `n log n = O(n^2)` true - false?
2. `2n – 3 = Θ(n)`    true - false?
3. `n^2 + 3 = Ω(n^3)` true - false?
4. `2n log n – 3n = O(n)` true - false?
5. `n^2 + 5n – 6 = Θ(n^2)` true - false?

Comment: half of them are true

Comment: That's cool but I dont know how to get it.. Can you explain me how can I get the result please?

Comment: you should do some research first... it looks like a "do my homework for me" question.

Comment: It is not homework I'm trying to find a guide how to do it lol

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, so I'll explain the whole picture and make one example:

```
f and g are functions, M is a positive constant, xi and xo are determined initial values.
f(x) = O(g(x)) iff |f(x)| <= M|g(x)| for all x > xi
f(x) = Ω(g(x)) iff |f(x)| > M|g(x)| for all x > xi
f(x) = Θ(g(x)) iff xi g(x) <= f(x) <= xo g(x)
```

For the first case we can prove that

```
Assuming n ∈ (0,∞).
Then logn<n, since n < 1+n < e^n by its Taylor series.
Thus, nlogn<n2 for all n ∈ (0,∞).
As a consequence, nlogn=O(n2).
```

So the process is the following, as I already know that logn < n and I know that n is a non-negative value, multiplying both sides by n I get nlogn < n^2.

By definition if f(x) <= kg(x) where k is a constant, I can say that f(x) = O(g(x)) and this is what happens above: nlogn <= kn^2, with k=1.

[another proof for logn < n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65202/how-to-prove-log-n-n)

[Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437769/how-to-prove-that-n-log-n-on2)

Comment: Hah I didn't get it I will have to study it for more hours :D I feel like E.T

Comment: @JakubStibůrek What didn't you get?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should know what the different symbols mean. For that, take at look here: [asymptotic notation on wolframalpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AsymptoticNotation.html)

There are various way to study and determine if these are true or false, (and your question is really a "do my homework please" one), but in general what you need to do is determine what happens "for arbitrarily large `n`"

As a quick and dirty way to it (not mathematically correct but often good enough for determining the complexity simple algorithms), you can just ignore all additive constants (e.g. `-2`, `+1`, ...) and evaluate what's left for two "big" n (like 1e9 and 1e13) and check the ratio. If it stays the same the two complexities are asymptotically "the same", if not one *asymptotically dominates* the other (= grows faster, which means that for large `n` you can ignore the other)

For a correct and complete mathematical approach, most Calculus courses treat the argument, you can surely find resources online, e.g. here: [growth of functions](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~pkirby/mad2104/SlideShow/s4_4.pdf)

Comment: No I'm just studying it now and that's some exercies. I will look on it.